# Batch file to move between symmetric folder structures

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I work in a project with symmetric folder structure, i.e:

- Master

  - Folder1

    - Folder_A1
  - Folder2
  - Folder3
- Slave

  - Folder1

    - Folder_A1
  - Folder2
  - Folder3

While I'm working, I usually change between master and slave to the same directories. I want to create a batchfile that helps me to switch only the maste/slave directory with this, i want something like this:

```
C:\Project\Master\Folder1\FolderA1>BatchFile
C:\Project\Slave\Folder1\FolderA1>
```

I plan to create 2 batches, toMaster and toSlave, that takes the current directory and replaces the "Master" String with the "Slave" and then move to that directory. Heres what I have so far in the toSlave batch:

```
@echo OFF
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set word=Slave
set "str=%cd%"
echo %str%
set str=%str:Master=!word!%
echo %str%    
pushd %str%
```

This seems to replace the strings correctly but when I run it from a terminal, it doesn't change my current directory. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Would `cd %str%` instead of `pushd %str%` work?

Comment: Would `Set "str=!str:Master=%word%!"` instead of `set str=%str:Master=!word!%` work?

Comment: Renat , It seems to work only in the context of the batch file execution. When I run `echo %cd%` after running `cd %str%` the directory will show in SLAVE however once the execution finishes and I'm in the prompt again, the cd in the terminal displays myself in the MASTER route

Comment: Compo, the same happens if I switch the line you suggested, The strings are replaced correctly but when change directory within the batch file as soon as it ends its execution my current directory in the prompt is the original one form which i started

Comment: You could of course forget about setting variables and try a single line command, `@If /I "%__CD__%"=="%__CD__:\Master\=%" (CD "%__CD__:\Slave\=\Master\%")Else If /I "%__CD__%"=="%__CD__:\Slave\=%"  CD "%__CD__:\Slave\=\Master\%"`. This of course would be a single batch file, instead of using two, _(it would effectively toggle between the two directory trees)_. You could then `Call` it from any batch file to switch your current directory to the other tree as necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work, because you did a `setlocal`. When the batch file ends, an implicite `endlocal` is executed, which undoes `pushd`. There is another reason you shouldn't use `pushd`: it saves the current location on a stack and doing it too often, may lead to a stack overflow. Better use `cd` instead.

Your batch file is very overloaded. Most of the lines are not needed and you can do the rest in just one command.

All you need for `toSlave.bat` is:

```
@cd /d "%__cd__:\Master\=\Slave\%"
```

(or you use @Compo's "Toggle" approach. It's quite elegant, but it's your job then to verify you are in the correct folder)

Comment: Stephan, I'm not sure what you mean by "it's your job then to verify you are in the correct folder", with reference to my "Toggle" approach. Notwithstanding that the same would be true of your current answer, it wouldn't change trees unless their current directory path contained either `\slave\ ` or `\master\ `, and a matching directory tree containing the other key word existed, _(I left out StdErr redirection so that the end user would know of such a failure)_. As a side note regarding your current answer, as the drive isn't changing, there's no need to include the `/D` option.

Comment: `/d` isn't necessary here, but it also doesn't hurt - and better be on the safe side. With "your job to verify" I mean If you do `toSlave`, you'll end in the `slave` branch independent of in which branch you were before. With the Toggle-approach, you need to be sure where you are / where you end.

Comment: For information, I used `%__CD__%` in my commented option, instead of `%CD%` because the replace string ends with a trailing backslash. `%__CD__%` will always carry a trailing backslash, which means that it will also work if the current directory is `C:\Project\Master`, _(`%__CD__%`=`C:\Project\Master\ `)_, or `C:\Project\Slave`,  _(`%__CD__%`=`C:\Project\Slave\ `)_. I also think I get your point about "where you are / where you end" to now, _(the script may not be in any master or slave branch at invokation time)_.

Comment: @Compo You are right about the difference between `%cd%` and the undocumented `%__cd__%`. I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpfull. Both solutions worked for me ! You've just made my life way easier